# Appending JSONArray with null based on condition java

Tags: java, arrays, json

i need the json objects output as below

```
{ name : primaryLevelPassed, //categoryName of passed student
  data : [123,110,106,null,null] },//passed object array
{ name : HighLevelPassed,     //categoryName of passed student
  data : [223,334,null,null,null] },//passed object array
{ name : primaryLevelFailed,  //categoryName of Failed student
  data : [null,null,null,23,44] },//failed object array
{ name : HighLevelFailed,     //categoryName of Failed student
  data : [null,null,06,23,44] }//data JSONArray(failed object array)
```

i want to show fixed number of data points in data JSONArray(i.e max_count = 5), where it should be appended with null at end and beginning depending on size and values.

Here i want to show points of both failed and passed, so for

1. failed object array, maintain max_count size, 
   a. if less than max_count append null at begin.
   b. If (failed students)>= max_count, keep max_count with latest studentIDs in desc order.
   c. if no failed students append all null
2. Passed object array, a. need to append failed lenght of null at end of array,keeping max_count size. b. If no failed students and (Passed students)>= max_count,keep max_count with latest studentIDs  in desc order. c. if no failed students append all null

code i am using now

```
    int max_count = 5;

    for(StudentCategory studentCategory : studentAgeCategoryList){ 

    JSONObject subData1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject subData2 = new JSONObject();
    //studentPassed
    List<Student> studentPassed = manager.getPassStudent(studentCategory.getCategoryId);
    for(Student student : studentPassed){
        subData1.put("name", studentCategory.getCategoryName()+"Passed");
        JSONArray series1DataPointsArray = new JSONArray(); 
        series1DataPointsArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(student.getTotalMark());
        subData1.put("data",series1DataPointsArray);                
    }   
    //studentFailed
    List<Student> studentFailed = manager.getFailedStudent(studentCategory.getCategoryId);      
    for(Student student : studentFailed){
        subData2.put("name", studentCategory.getCategoryName()+"Failed");
        JSONArray series2DataPointsArray = new JSONArray();     
        series2DataPointsArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(student.getTotalMark());
        subData2.put("data",series2DataPointsArray);    
    }
    }
this code gives output
{ name : primaryLevelPassed,
data : [123,110,106,444,223,334,106....] }
   { name : HighLevelFailed,
data : [123,110,106,444,223,334,106....] }
```

Can please anyone help me to get output like above with nulls.

Comment: you are question is not clear, could you be specific on what you want ??? use sample input and output for example to relate your question

Comment: @Ravi i want output shown with nulls. Let me know if u have any questions

Comment: I see no difference in two list . why ?

Comment: @Ravi there is difference of nulls, read the discription

Comment: No, I said, about your output. check and update your expected output

Comment: @Ravi This is my expected output { name : primaryLevelPassed,
    data : [123,110,106,null,null] },
  { name : HighLevelPassed,
    data : [223,334,null,null,null] },
  { name : primaryLevelFailed,
    data : [null,null,null,23,44] },
  { name : HighLevelFailed,
    data : [null,null,06,23,44] }